GraphQL CodeGen Enum Deprecation Not Generating in TypeScript
I have a GraphQL schema with deprecated enum values generated by GraphQL Codegen, but the generated TypeScript types don't include the deprecation annotations
The enum is used to generate the GraphQL schema below. i use @nestjs/graphql
export enum PaymentType {
  /**
   * @deprecated Cash payments are no longer supported.
   */
  Cash = 'Cash',
  CreditCard = 'CreditCard',
  /**
   * @deprecated Use `DigitalWallet` instead.
   */
  PayPal = 'PayPal',
  DigitalWallet = 'DigitalWallet',
}

registerEnumType(PaymentMethod, {
  name: 'PaymentMethod',
  valuesMap: {
    PayPal: {
      deprecationReason: 'Use `DigitalWallet` instead',
    },
    Cash: {
      deprecationReason: 'Cash payments are no longer supported.',
    },
  },
});

GraphQL Schema generated from the above enum
enum PaymentType {
  CASH @deprecated(reason: "Cash payments are no longer supported")
  CREDIT_CARD
  DIGITAL_WALLET @deprecated(reason: "Use MOBILE_PAYMENT instead")
  MOBILE_PAYMENT
}

Generated TypeScript type that generated from above grapqQL type
this doesn't include the deprecated fields
export enum PaymentType {
  CASH = 'CASH',
  CREDIT_CARD = 'CREDIT_CARD',
  DIGITAL_WALLET = 'DIGITAL_WALLET',
  MOBILE_PAYMENT = 'MOBILE_PAYMENT'
}

Expected TypeScript output
export enum PaymentType {
  /** @deprecated Cash payments are no longer supported */
  CASH = 'CASH',
  CREDIT_CARD = 'CREDIT_CARD',
  /** @deprecated Use MOBILE_PAYMENT instead */
  DIGITAL_WALLET = 'DIGITAL_WALLET',
  MOBILE_PAYMENT = 'MOBILE_PAYMENT'
}

